# MWAA in productions - tasks queued for unknown reasons

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x, mwaa

Does anyone use MWAA in production?

We currently have around 500 DAGs running and we see an unexpected behavior with tasks staying in a "queued" state for unknown reasons.

> Task is in the 'queued' state which is not a valid state for
> execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.

It happens randomly, can perfectly run for a day and then a few tasks will stay queued. The tasks will stay in this state forever unless we mark them as failed manually.

A DAG run can stay in this "queued" state even if the pool is empty, I don't see any reasons explaining this.

It happens to ~5% of the tasks with all the others running smoothly.

Did you ever encounter this behavior?

Comment: whats the version of airflow you are using?

Comment: Airflow version is 2.0.2

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing occurring for `MWAA v.2.2.2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was happening to me in MWAA as well. The solution, recommended to me by AWS, was adding to **Airflow configuration options** via the web UI the following options:

```
celery.sync_parallelism = 1 
core.dag_file_processor_timeout = 150
core.dagbag_import_timeout = 90 
core.min_serialized_dag_update_interval = 300
scheduler.dag_dir_list_interval = 600 
scheduler.min_file_process_interval = 300
scheduler.parsing_processes = 2 
scheduler.processor_poll_interval = 60
```

Comment: Did they say why this would work? What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

We faced the similar issue.

We solved this by increasing the no of minimum workers to 2 (one base worker + one additional worker)

MWAA has autoscaling to spin up additional worker when running tasks or queued tasks increase. Spinning up takes some time.

`In small MWAA env (running tasks + queued tasks) / 5 = no. of workers needed`

We checked in CloudWatch metrics that whenever these no of workers needed were > 2, we were facing the issue.

However one more issue is that once a task is picked by an additional worker and that worker is marked to be destroyed (due to autoscaling down), then that task remains in queued state for longer time.